# Java-How to create an explosion with drawn rectangles?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jframe, jpanel

I need to make an explosion animation for my 2d Java swing game.
I need it with multiple yellow rectangles, that literally "explode". 
My solution was to give each rectangle a different x and y because every rectangle has to go to another direction. The problem is, that I don't how to do this efficiently. Sorry for bad English, please help me. Any help is appreaciated

Comment: What do you mean by "explode"? Fly into pieces or actually display an explosion animation?

Comment: multiple small rectangles flying to nowhere(from one point)

Comment: It looks like you're going to need at least a rudimentary physics engine to calculate the position and orientation of each piece over time.

Comment: Okay thanks, now I know this would be too difficult with only java swing

Comment: To set velocity of rectangles just use Random class and set velocityX and velocityY randomly. After that every game logic tick you move these rectangles in direction of their velocity and slowly fade them out via alpha , any questions?

Comment: But, do I have to make different x and y coordinates for each rectangle, because if use one x and y for all of them, they will not "explode", but all go to one direction each time

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very rough outline of what you need to do. For anything more complicated you'll really need a more robust physics engine.

Each piece of the rectangle is represented by an instance of a class (`Piece`, shall we call it?). All of these `Piece`s are generated when the rectangle explodes. The `Piece` class stores information of their x and y positions, their velocity on the x and y axes, their rotation stored in radians, and their angular velocity. All of these values can pretty much be randomly generated if you're just going for a basic explosion effect.

You're going to have to constantly calculate the physics for the game (constantly simulate physics "ticks") and constantly draw the pieces onto the component. This could mean two separate loops, or you could do them together - just don't flood the EDT.

The "tick" is an operation that is applied at a constant rate (say 30 times per second) and does the following:

- Add the x and y velocity of the pieces to the position variables, respectively
- Add the rotation velocity variable to the rotation angle variable
- Reduce the velocity variables towards zero, if you'd like a resistance effect applied on them

And after the tick is complete, you call `repaint()` on your component. The component can iterate over the `Piece` classes however you'd like and render them on screen (don't forget about the rotation).

Hopefully this gets you started. Obviously there are a lot of changes and optomizations that need to be made when you go for scalability in a physics engine - but this should give you an idea of how the concept works. I also haven't mentioned synchronization at all which is something you definitely need to take into account if you're dealing with Swing and a physics loop.

If you'd like to look into making physics engines a little more, I'd recommend [this series](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331). Hopefully you like math.